# How to update Heroku database with new columns while database is live?

Tags: python, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have a live Heroku psql database using Flask with data that I need. However, I also need to update the database with new columns in a table. Whenever I update the table and push it to Heroku, the app shuts down saying that the original data does not follow the new schema. So what is the best way to update database structures with the data is hosted on Heroku?

For example:
models_original.py

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

to
models_new.py

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Are you using database migrations? Generally, you'd deploy your new code and then run your migrations.

Comment: @Chris No I am not. Is it too late to add database migrations (or is it too late)?

Comment: It's always best to use them from the beginning, but you should be able to start now. I think [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the most popular migration library for Flask and SQLAlchemy. (This doesn't exactly solve your problem, though. With migrations you'd push your new code and then run your migrations. Without them, you'd push your new code and then modify your database some other way. In both cases the code and database will be briefly out of sync. Migrations are still a really good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

### Migrations

The generally accepted, as in a best practise approach, is to use a library or another solution for managing database migrations — adding, removing, renaming columns, tables, indexes and so on. As Chris pointed out in the comments, [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a popular solution for database migrations with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

A migration, updating a column or a table, would happen as part of your deploy process, right before the application is restarted. Care must be taken with "destructive" migrations (removing, renaming columns and tables), because with zero-downtime deployments there will be the "previous version" app running at the time of the migration. That "previous version" app will have the "previous version" SQLAlchemy models which, at that point, have extra columns or columns with the wrong name. This will result in errors, as you're seeing right now.

#### Your issue with updating a table

As for the problem you're having with updating a table and getting errors, I suspect you either made a mistake in the description of the problem or there is some other misunderstanding. You said:

> Whenever I update the **table** and push it to Heroku, the app shuts down saying that the original data does not follow the new schema.

You should not have to push any code if you aren't using a migration library and are manually updating the table in Postgres.

Your code samples, however, suggest that you are updating the SQLAlchemy **model** definition, not the Postgres **table** structure. If you update the model — e.g add a column — and it doesn't match the table structure, SQLAlchemy will throw errors.